# oledb command executeNonQuery is running against wrong path

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

I have the following code in a WPF app:

```
TargetCon.Open();

foreach (var table in accessTables)
{
    var tableConfig = _centralConfig.DataTablesForExport.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == table).Single();

    _serilog.WriteString("Going to add index for table: " + tableConfig.Name);

    foreach (var index in tableConfig.IndexColumns)
    {
        var command = new OleDbCommand($"CREATE INDEX idx{index.ColumnName} ON {tableConfig.Name}({index.ColumnName})", TargetCon);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

When stepping through the code in debug, on the line `command.ExecuteNoneQuery()`, an exception is raised that it's unable to find file at the `\in\debug` folder of the project. I don't know why it's looking in that folder. If I inspect the public property `TargetCon`, I see that the `DataSource` property of that object is set correctly to a path `c:\databases\u2.mdb`.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on foreach, What's the value of targetCon.ConnectionString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql statement was trying to create an index on a table name that didn't exist. Not a very helpful error message - which caused my to venture down the wrong path to resolve.

Once I fixed the sql statement, the problem was resolved

Comment: I have given more detail at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281347/oledbcommand-using-wrong-path