# OleDbCommand using wrong path

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, oledbconnection

I have the following c# code in a WPF app:

```
var command = new OleDbCommand($"CREATE INDEX idx{index.ColumnName} ON {tableConfig.Name}({index.ColumnName})", _targetCon);
                    try
                    {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex1) { _serilog.WriteError(METHOD_NAME, "Trouble adding index onto Access column", ex1); }
```

My problem is that when stepping through the code in the VS debugger, the line "command.ExecuteNonQuery();" is throwing an exception. At the time of the exception, the value of _targetCon.ConnectionString is `"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=C:\AccessDatabases\APMS\unit3.mdb;"` and the value of the _targetCon.DataSource is: `C:\AccessDatabases\APMS\unit3.mdb` This is the correct path. However, the value of ex2.Message is `"Could not find file 'C:\Git_RB\AccessMigration\AccessLauncher\AccessLauncher.WPF\bin\Debug\Unit3.mdb'"`

If I run the app outside of VS then I find that it's still trying to find the file in the database in the same folder as the exe:

[image]

Why is the command object ignoring the properties of its connection object and looking in the wrong path?

Comment: What is the actual value of the SQL statement? Maybe it contains unusual table or indexes names. Is the affected table a normal table or a linked table (i.e. a table pointing to another database)?

Comment: You got it @FrankM! The sql statement was trung to create an index on a  table name that didn't exist. Not a very helpful error message though. Could you please add as answer and I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the actual value of the SQL statement that you are using. It might contain another table name than the one you expect, e.g. due to string truncation.